# ADMob test ad not appearing IOS

Tags: swift, admob

I have read all other posts about this and none of the solutions have worked. I have linked my `GADBannerView` to the `viewController` from the `storyboard`. I have followed a tutorial but when I run my test there is nothing in the place where the test ad should be.

This is how I implement it

```
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.adUnitID = "/* My Uint ID */"
    adBannerView.rootViewController = self
    adBannerView.load(request)
```

This does not work. I have no idea why this would be as the tutorial I followed did the exact same as me and everything went fine. I get no errors, just nothing shows up as if the View is being removed somehow.

What should I do to fix this?

If you need anything else, I can update my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this? `viewDidLoad`? have you tried adding the `adBannerView` programmatically?

Comment: have  you used "adUnitId "test id given by admob

Comment: Sometimes Simulator not showing the Ads. You can try to run on simulator using selecting different device Selection. That may works. Or you can run on actual device.

Comment: Yes. This is in `viewDidload`. I have not tried to add it programmatically because it is a lot easier to add constraints in the IB. I have used `adUnitId`. You can see it in my question. I tried running this on simulator and a device. Same results.